# How do I change the default PHP sort order to alphabetic in a WP Loop?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page that is creating a WP Loop that creates a list of pages, and I'd like to change the default sort to be alphabetical. This is the WordPress loop.

```
<?php
        $i = 1;
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

            $postid                 = get_the_ID();
            $terms                  = get_the_terms($postid, 'program_categories' );
            $terms2                 = get_the_terms($postid, 'program_type' );
            $permalink              = get_permalink( $postid  );
            $title                  = get_the_title( $postid  );
            $raw_date               = the_modified_date('F j, Y','','',false);
            $d                      = strtotime($raw_date);
            $all_terms              = '';

            if ( !empty( $terms ) ) { foreach ($terms as $term) { $all_terms .= strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->name)). ' '; } }
            if ( !empty( $terms2 ) ) { foreach ($terms2 as $term2) { $all_terms .= strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term2->name)). ' '; } }


            ?>
```

These are the buttons for changing the sort after the page loads, in case this helps provide info.

```
<li><a href="#" class="active" data-sort-value="i"><?php _e('Default','swmtranslate'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-sort-value="list_title"><?php _e('Alphabetical','swmtranslate'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-sort-value="date"><?php _e('Last Updated','swmtranslate'); ?></a></li>
```

Is it as simple as adding something like this to the beginning of the loop?

```
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post("SELECT * FROM $title ORDER BY ASC");
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP really and is all about Wordpress. A PHP loop simply loops, it doesn't sort. The sorting needs to be done by whatever is providing the data.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query it's so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered [right in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). You need to define an `orderby` and `order` parameter in your query args:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Gotcha, and this would be what I have there:
     $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'programs',
            'orderby'=>'menu_order',
            'order'     => 'ASC',

Comment: ...So why aren't you changing the `orderby` to `title`?

Comment: It seemed too damn simple! Thanks very much, that was it! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will be helpfull for your question. You need to set your custom query to short by title something like this.

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

([Alphabetizing Posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts))

Answer (score 0):

Your full code will be like this:

```
        <?php
        $i = 1;
       $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

        $postid                 = get_the_ID();
        $terms                  = get_the_terms($postid, 'program_categories' );
        $terms2                 = get_the_terms($postid, 'program_type' );
        $permalink              = get_permalink( $postid  );
        $title                  = get_the_title( $postid  );
        $raw_date               = the_modified_date('F j, Y','','',false);
        $d                      = strtotime($raw_date);
        $all_terms              = '';

        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) { foreach ($terms as $term) { $all_terms .= strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->name)). ' '; } }
        if ( !empty( $terms2 ) ) { foreach ($terms2 as $term2) { $all_terms .= strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term2->name)). ' '; } }


        ?>
```